# Upload Multiple Files with FuelPHP and save files information in separate database table

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

Can someone suggest me how to do next:

I have two database table - 'products' and 'products_photo'
I want adding my products to update my products table and information about uploaded photos to be saved into the separated table.

I uploaded photos and the table about products is filled corectly but my table `products_photos` is empty.

my controler_product contains

```
            // Custom configuration for this upload
            $config = array(
                'path' => DOCROOT.DS.'images',
                'randomize' => true,
                'ext_whitelist' => array('img', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'),
            );

             Upload::process($config);

             // if a valid file is passed than the function will save, or if its not empty
            if (Upload::is_valid())
            {
                // save them according to the config
                 Upload::save();

                 //if you want to save to tha database lets grab the file name
                Model_Products_Photo::add(Upload::get_files());
            } // and process any errors
            foreach (Upload::get_errors() as $file)
            {
             // $file is an array with all file information,
             // $file contains an array of all error occurred
             // each array element is an an array containing 'error' and 'message'
             }
```

And my model `products_photo` contains

```
   public static function add($file)
   {  print_r($file);

     Model_Products_Photo::forge( $file[0]);


   }
```

I assume here in this function is something wrong...
I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: database structure? Are you sure that your photo model contains fields from the uploaded file structure?

Comment: That contains next fields:'id',
  'filename',
  'fpath',
  'products_id',
  'created_at',
  'updated_at',         Does that need to contain every one?

Comment: Do you save your models at all?

Comment: Yes, I did...public static function add($products_photos)
       {  print_r($products_photos);
          
         $photo = Model_Products_Photo::forge( $products_photos[0]);
   $photo->save();
   
   
       }

Comment: Could you please update your code, because what you posted is not the same as your last comment.

Comment: I resolve that...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in is_valid() you give like this.,,

```
  Upload::save();
  $variable=upload::get_files();
  foreach($variable as $img){
   $img_name=$img['saved_as'];
  }
```